# Constant StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I'm preparing for a upcoming test and trying to understand how substring works.
Please explain to me cause I don't really get the explanations online.
My error is: StringIndexOutOfBounds Exception
I don't understand how its causing the error as when calling substring to extract a string, it would automatically -1 from the endIndex. Thats why i added 1, but its not working.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the string: ");
        String string = scn.nextLine();


        System.out.print("Enter the start char: ");
        char startChar = scn.next().charAt(0);


        System.out.print("Enter the end char: ");
        char endChar = scn.next().charAt(string.length() - 1);

        int startIndex = string.indexOf(startChar); //Get index of the start character
        int endIndex = string.indexOf(endChar);

        if(startIndex == -1) {
            System.out.println("No such substring"); //First char doesn't exist
        }
        else {
            if(endIndex == -1) {
                System.out.println("No such substring");
            }
            else {
                String extractedString = string.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1); //Cause sub string is -1
                System.out.println("Substring [" + extractedString + "]" + " is found");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried going through a debugger?

Comment: What did you provide for the input data?

Comment: For the string: Fibonacci series, for start char: F for end char: b

Comment: You want to read a single character with `scn.next().charAt(string.length() - 1);`, but it look like you mixed it up with accessing a character at the end of your first input.

Comment: Is it the `substring` method that's throwing the exception? Or is it earlier than that (as I suspect)?

Comment: char endChar = scn.next().charAt(string.length() - 1); cause the exception please do the proper code in this place.

Comment: @KevinEsche what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
char endChar = scn.next().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you're doing is you're calling `scn.next()`, and taking the char at `string.length-1` from that `scn.next()` call. How long is `string`, and how long is `scn.next()`?